# how to find partial text in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two columns "A" & "B". Column "A" contains Complete Text (1000 line items) & Column "B" contains partial text (250 line items). How I can find & place all Partial text(Column B) line items against Complete Text (Column A) line items or their ROW numbers in which partial text is appearing.

```
**Column A**
Two Apples are Sweet
Three Apples are Bitter
Five Apples are Sour
Two Grapes are Sweet
Three Grapes are Bitter
Five Grapes are Sour
Two Chilies are Sweet
Three Chilies are Bitter
Five Chilies are Sour
```

---

```
**Column B**
Apple
Chili
Grapes
```

Thanks in anticipation of your help & Support.
Regards
Anil

Comment: What do you mean? If you find "Apple" from Col B in Col A, you'll return 3 instances of apple. What do you want?

Comment: If you mean "Find all instances of 'Apple' and replace it with something else" then your best solution may be a short VBA script because there would be 250 find and replace actions. However, we still don't know what you want to replace "Apple" *with* so we can't get very far yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "Find all instances of 'Apple' and replace it with something else" then your best solution may be a short VBA script because there would be 250 find and replace actions. However, we still don't know what you want to replace "Apple" with so we can't get very far yet. If you had the replacement values in column `C`, then your data sheet may look like this CSV:

> Six Apples are Sweet,Apple,Monkey
>   Three Apples are Bitter,Chili,Elephant
>   Five Apples are Sour,Grapes,Cow
>   Six Grapes are Sweet,,
>   Three Grapes are Bitter,,
>   Five Grapes are Sour,,
>   Six Chilies are Sweet,,
>   Three Chilies are Bitter,,
>   Five Chilies are Sour,,

... in which case this VBA loop through every cell in column `B`, find the text in column `A`, and replace it with text from column `C`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub replaceAllText()
    Dim r As Long
    Dim findString As String
    Dim replaceString As String
    With ActiveSheet
        For r = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            findString = .Cells(r, 2)
            If LenB(findString) > 0 Then
                replaceString = .Cells(r, 3)
                .Columns("A:A").Replace What:=findString, Replacement:=replaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

And give you a result like this:

> Six Monkeys are Sweet,Apple,Monkey
>   Three Monkeys are Bitter,Chili,Elephant
>   Five Monkeys are Sour,Grapes,Cow
>   Six Cow are Sweet,,
>   Three Cow are Bitter,,
>   Five Cow are Sour,,
>   Six Elephantes are Sweet,,
>   Three Elephantes are Bitter,,
>   Five Elephantes are Sour,,